# Is there any risk in sending copies of my ID and utility bills to a company that cold-called me?

Tags: united-states, scams, billing, utilities

I'm shopping around for solar and a company called me.

I'm a bit suspicious, due to some what I think might be red flags:

1. The first caller could answer few questions, spoke with a heavy accent, could not tell me details about their physical store in the local area (they said the reason was they have many offices).
2. I never gave my personal details out to any solar company. They addressed me by someone else's name...a name I often used to address in text scams, like "buy warranty for car" or "refund for computer services", so they clearly got my *wrong* name and phone number from the same place scammers are getting it.
3. They want me to E-mail them a copy of my utility bill and photo ID.
4. They promise to pay me more than hundred dollars if I sit through their on-line meeting and send the items in #3 to them.

I am genuinely interested in having solar installed, but suspicious. Is there a danger of providing this information to them? Is that likely normal procedures for a solar company to request this information?

Comment: It's a scam.  Legitimate business provide business details and do not request personal data for estimates.  At best, you should provide a redacted copy of your utility bill.  Redacted means physically cutting out your name, address, account number, etc.  get referrals from friends with solar.  If none, contact the Better Business Bureau for company information.

Comment: Utility bills are often used as secondary proofs of identity.  (It's why I still have mine snail mailed.)  Thus, your red flag 3 rings a loud alarm to me.

Comment: Why are you more concerned about sending a copy of your utility bill than your photo ID? I would think the latter is more dangerous.

Comment: So they cold called you requesting intimate information that is absolutely sufficient for Identity Theft AND massively exceeds anything necessary for a quote? RUN !!!!!

Comment: If you want solar, search around for reputable local solar installers in your area and *contact them*. Then you know you're dealing with someone who's above board. Some solar installers *will* ask for a copy of the electric bill to gauge your usage (and thus what size system you will need), but to solicit that off the bat, and to use your "fake" details is a huge red flag. Also as Bob said, a legit solar company will be happy with a fully redacted bill (so all that's visible is your electrical usage).

Comment: The main reason solar installer needs your electric bill is to estimate your power consumption, so they know how many panels you need to install. The secondary reason is to see how much you pay for your electricity, so they can market it to you as "you will get your investment back in X years".

Comment: @RonJohn: I'm curious about your rationale. As someone with some experience in computer hacking, I would find it much easier to steal someone's mail than their email. Not trivial, but easier.

Comment: @MartinArgerami stealing someone's snail mail means physically having to travel to their residence.  That's fine if you live in the area and know the address.  Not so much if you're a remote scammer.

Comment: I am assuming your state allows you to choose a residential electric provider like e.g. [Massachusetts does](https://www.energyswitchma.gov).  Then your electric bill has enough information (specifically your account number) for the caller to switch your electric provider from your current provider to some other provider.  Basically the equivalent of [phone slamming](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/slamming-switching-your-authorized-telephone-company-without-permission) for electricity.  See: [Energy Bill Scam Calls](https://blog.mass.gov/consumer/massconsumer/energy-bill-scam-calls/).

Comment: The main danger is that they may be **shocked.**

Comment: No offence intended, but to me this sounds like "a guy is pointing a gun to my head, should I be worried?"

Comment: Could you change the title to "electricity bill"?

Comment: Even assuming it's entirely legitimate, responding encourages cold-callers.

Comment: As an aside, you will **never save money with solar** if you go with someone who's made a business out of getting people on solar, especially if you have to ask such a basic question about a scam as this one. Most of the business models are structured such that they're using your property to make themselves money off the solar installation. If you want to even break even, much less save money, you **must** research the economics and technical aspects of solar yourself, source cost-effective components, and pay someone up front for installation labor.

Comment: Given the attention this question has received, it might be helpful for you to dig a little bit and find out if this is a legitimate company or a scam. Does the company have a phone number you can call directly? Do they have a website? Did the solar company call you or was it a third party sales person? Why do they need the ID at this early stage? Do they have reviews? This would make for a nice update to your question. Most of the answers are doing a lot of speculation here about whether this is legit or not (my answer included), and you may have the ability to find out for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose they really are selling solar electric systems.  Perhaps they are engaged in other kinds of fraud instead, in which case your ID and bill could be used to buy other expensive things on merchant credit (e.g. a used automobile; jewelry; i-phones).

So these solar generators are expensive systems, and they earn sales commissions.  I speculate the sales commission is a lot more than the $100 they offer you to listen -- which means the systems may be hyped. They probably need to be either sold on credit or leased.  They may work with a finance company or bank that requires a signed contract, photo id of buyer, and confirmation of address (e.g. a residential bill).  If you give them the last two, they only need your signature.  They
might also obtain your signature at a sign-in book for the meeting, or on your photo id.  By copying/forging your signature they would have a sale and earn their sales commission.  It might cost a lot of money to reverse an undesired sale.

The electric bill can also be used for either truthful or hyped-up marketing, and for the legitimate purpose of deciding how many solar panels are required to meet residential electric usage. Electricity usage for heating and cooling is seasonal though I suppose one could make a rough estimate of maximum usage from a single bill -- with the excess sold back to the local utility.

Of course, it could simply be a slightly-less sleazy business where sales are streamlined by copying everything needed from the ID and electric bill to the sales contract, which is ready for you to simply sign. You won't know unless you play the game -- something I would not risk.  There are other companies that don't use high pressure sales techniques.

Comment: FWIW, some utilities also include historical usage data on the bill; for example, my provider has both a graph and a table of the past year's usage in a sidebar. This information is useful to *legitimate* solar vendors. Of course an electric bill is also useful to fraudsters for a number of other purposes too...

Answer (score 34):

I'm more wary of the photo ID than the utility bill. I haven't pulled the trigger on solar but I did do some price shopping. Every company needed a copy of my electric bill in order to provide a quote but I don't recall them needing my ID at the initial quote stage. The request very well could be legit though, especially if the company calling you is a third party sales lead generator for a solar company. The utility bill is what's needed for the quote and the photo ID could be what's needed for the sales team to prove their leads are real so it's harder for them to fake them to inflate their commission.

Regardless, I wouldn't entertain a cold call. Research some solar companies that you want to deal with, ask your neighbors who they have or are dealing with, and stick to them. If you initiate the phone call you don't have to worry about whether the company calling you is real or not.

As for what a scammer could do if they have a copy of your utility bill, there's nothing in the bill itself that is sacred so the information itself isn't really a risk. But having an actual copy of a bill could be used as a secondary piece of information which is sometimes required for proof of residency. Putting that together with a photo ID could enable someone to create a new photo ID with your information and initiate identity theft. Again, unless you were specifically targeted (which is unlikely if they didn't know your real name) it's probably a legitimate sales call, but I wouldn't take the risk in case it's scammy instead of just scummy.

As a side note, if a solar company cold calls and you actually want to test them, explain that you don't think you have an electric bill so ask if you can provide a water utility bill instead. (Sounds crazy but if you think it through a scammer is likely to agree to this if they just need proof of residency for identity theft.) If they do say yes then you know with 100% certainty it's a scam.

Comment: Seconded--they're using the electric bill to size the system.  It really should be 12 months of usage information, though.  I've never been asked for ID when getting solar quotes, though.

Comment: As suggested by BobBaerker, you could also offer a redacted copy of your bill -- a scanned copy where you've completely blacked out at least your name, address, and account numbers (name and address are critical for address verification/proof of residency scams, account numbers for [slamming](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/slamming) scams).

Comment: @DoktorJ you definitely could do that, and I think the solar company would be OK with that if you're dealing directly with them. But I doubt a third party sales person (which is my guess as to what this call was) would accept that because they need to prove to their customer (the solar company) that the lead is valid. And then you of course wouldn't be providing the ID either...

Comment: @LorenPechtel every one of my monthly electric bills contains the graph and numbers of the previous 12 months. I don't know if that's the norm or not.

Comment: My water and electricity and wastewater bills are combined in Austin, TX, into a total utilities bill. Besides the TV and the internet (of which we have many options), the city runs most of our utilities.

Comment: @TTT Mine contains a small graph, not really suitable for sizing a system.

Comment: @BillBarth I guess my idea to test the scammer wouldn't work for you; at least not with the water bill. ;)

Comment: I work at a power company and am currently on a project trying to deal with the amount of crap caused by these solar cold-callers. They will log a connection application on your behalf as soon as they get your address, even before they have your name, and fill in the rest with crap data. Even if they aren't actually scammers, they are as bad as them.

Comment: I would add to the comment of @LorenPechtel, any solar company that sizes your system without looking at a full years consumption data isn't worth engaging in my opinion.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, then why don't they just ask for the needed information, instead of a document that contains much more?

Comment: @TTT speaking as the guy who actually works on the software that creates those bills for hundreds of utilities, that's pretty much the norm. Not having a graph is definitely the exception

Comment: @I'mwithMonica probably because they have more chance of getting them from the bill, as very few users are aware of their actual consumption and usage pattern, even if they show interest in solar. A lot of other utility companies with new customers give you the choice of giving previous bills or to select the usage yourself, so that if you are not sure can just give the bill and let them figure it out.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica Because the average person isn't going to do a good job of getting the information off the bill.

Comment: "As for what a scammer could do if they have a copy of your utility bill, there's nothing in the bill itself that is sacred so the information itself isn't really a risk." - note that this is country dependant. You are probably correct about US, don't have an idea how it is there and this is tagged as such. But for example in UK, an utility bill goes a long way to prove you live somewhere (and is pretty much the standard way to prove such a thing), so would not sent it to fishy parties.

Comment: @eis: That's pointed out in literally the very next sentence.

Answer (score 25):

Identity theft, probably.

Photo ID is not something a business has a legitimate interest in, unless the business is granting you a loan.

Where I live, it is pretty much usual to ask a customer to show a recent utility bill (electricity, water) as a weak form of a postal address verification.

Both things may or may not be enough to get you a loan. Here, a bank would not do that, but one can pretty much get a quick and expensive loan from a half-legitimate credit institution.

Other risks (as per comments below grom @vikingsteve) include getting a SIM card or bank account in your name.

Comment: Definitely this. OP should be wary. Photo ID plus an electricity bill is enough to do a lot of things in someone else's name, from getting a SIM card to opening a bank account.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer to the  question 'what's the danger?'  Utility bills are often an option for multi-document identify verification.

Answer (score 5):

### It's *slamming*

*Slamming* is when they switch your utility provider without your knowledge.

Look at your electric bill.  You will find separate line-items for the cost of *distribution of power* (use of the lines going to your house) and cost of *generating that power*.

You can't change your distribution company - that's your local power company (Edison). But you can change your *generating* company, e.g. to select a zero-carbon energy provider.  This "bills through" on your regular electric bill from your local distributor (e.g. Edison).  It's only seen in the "fine print".

**Slamming** is changing your "generating company" without your consent, hoping you will not notice the fine print.  Last time I investigated one, they used independent salesmen and paid them commission-only, **at $600 per signup**.

That alone is a heck of an incentive to "scam you".  Either by flat out slamming you without consent, or by wrapping it in a sales-job of some kind.

### And/or it's *lead generation*

There is also a healthy marketplace in **qualified sales leads**.  Once they have screened you as genuinely interested in solar, real solar companies will pay for that. That isn't *technically* a scam, it's a common sales funnel technique... but the "highest bidders" for your details are often companies *that aren't very good*.

Referring you out to a real solar company also covers part of a "slamming" scam, if they convinced you to change power supplier by claiming it's part of getting solar.

### By the way... be a smart consumer with solar

You probably know this but it's gotta be said for readers: **Solar systems WILL NOT power your house during a power outage**! This can be done, but considerations need to be made for that *at the beginning*. And with mindfulness for who actually owns the system, because some deals get very tricky-dicky.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the U.S., but in Germany, if you want to change your utility provider, they only need your meter ID number to process this. There have been cases where a change to another provider was performed without the customer wanting this.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: It's touching on an issue called "slamming", which indeed is huge in the USA.